# Mobile responsive have overflow-y

Tags: css, css-grid

Trying to find issue two days and maybe I miss something. I create grid website. All working fine, but when is on mobile view have overflow-y. When I create template all be fine, and when start adding styles and colors, then problem start. I don't know why, if anyone can check code and tell me what I wrong. Thanks

```css
:root {
    --first: #7d9aff;
    --hover: #9bbeff;
}
body {
    font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif;
    max-height:100%;
    margin: 0;
}

h1 { font-size: 70px }
h2 { font-size: 50px }
h3 { font-size: 30px }
h4 { font-size: 20px }
p { font-size: 18px }
a { text-decoration: none; }

ul.korisniLinkoiv {
    padding-left: 7px;
    font-size: 18px;
}
.korisniLinkoiv li {
    list-style-type: none;
}

.korisniLinkoiv li a {
    color: white;
}

.top,
.menu,
.features,
.webDesign,
.webHosting,
.servisRacunara,
.podrska {
    margin: 15px;
    font-size: 15px;
}

button {
    background: var(--first);
    color: white;
    border: 0;
    padding: 10px 20px;
}

button:hover {
    background: #5979ce;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#btn-large {
    padding: 18px 55px;
    font-size: 14px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 7px rgba(155, 190, 255, 0.52);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 5px 7px rgba(155, 190, 255, 0.52);
    box-shadow: 0 5px 7px rgba(155, 190, 255, 0.52);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease 0.0s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease 0.0s;
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0.0s;
}

#btn-large:hover {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1) rotate(4deg);
    transform: scale(1.1) rotate(4deg);
}

img {
    max-width: 100%;
}

/* .wrapper */

.wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 20px;
}

/* Top */

.top {
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 20px;
    grid-template-areas:
        "hero hero cta1"
        "hero hero cta2";
    min-height: 97vh;
 }

.hero {
    grid-area: hero;
    min-height: 400px;
    background: url(assets/images/razvoj.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: bottom right;
    padding: 50px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: start;
    justify-content: center;
}

.hero > * {
    background: var(--first);
    padding: 5px;
}

.cta {
    background: var(--first);
    display: grid;
    align-items: center;
    justify-items: center;
    align-content: center;
}

.cta p {
    margin: 0;
}

.cta1 {
    grid-area: cta1;
}

.cta2 {
    grid-area: cta2;
}

.price {
    font-size: 60px;
    font-weight: 300;
}

/* Navigation */

.menu ul {
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 10px;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(100px, 1fr));
}


.menu li a {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 34px;
    background: var(--first);
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.menu a {
    display: block;
    margin: 1px;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    color: var(--black);
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 20px;
    background: white;
    box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}

.menu a:hover {
    background: var(--hover);
    color: white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    transition: ease-out 200ms;
}

[aria-controls="menu-list"] {
    display: none;
}

/* Features! */

.features {
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 20px;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(200px, 1fr));
}

.feature {
    background: white;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid white;
    text-align: center;
    box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}

.feature p {
    color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

.icon {
    width: 130px;
}

/* webDesign, webHosting, servisRacunara, podrska Section */

.webDesign,
.webHosting,
.servisRacunara,
.podrska {
    background: white;
    padding: 50px;
    min-height: 400px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-gap: 20px;
    align-items: center;
    justify-items: center;
}

.about {
    background: url("assets/images/clouds.png");
}

img.about__mockup {
    width: 350px;
}

/* Gallery */

.gallery {
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 20px;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(400px, 1fr));
}

.gallery img {
    width: 100%;
}

/* Counter Statistika */

section.statistika {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    padding: 50px;
    background-image: url("assets/images/stats.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: bottom right;
}

.stats {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: white;
}

.counter-value{
    padding: 0 50px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 70px;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: white;
}

/* Kontakt */

.kontakt {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    text-align: center;
    justify-items: center;
    align-items: center;
}

footer {
    text-align: center;
}

/* Web Dizajn Page */

.website li a {
    background: #9e027b;
}

.website a:hover {
    background: #c3278b;
}

button.website {
    background: #9e027b;
}

button.website:hover {
    background: #c3278b;
}

.top-page {
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 20px;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    min-height: 200px;
}

.header-line {
    min-height: 200px;
    background: url(assets/images/trianglify.svg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: bottom right;
    padding: 50px;
    color: #000;
}

/* Portfolio section */

.portfolio h2 {
    grid-column: 1 / -1;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr auto 1fr;
    grid-gap: 20px;
    align-items: center;
}

.portfolio h2:before, .portfolio h2:after {
    display: block;
    content: '';
    height: 10px;
    background: linear-gradient(to var(--direction, left), var(--first), transparent);
}

.portfolio h2:after {
    height: 10px;
    --direction: right;
}


@media (max-width: 1000px) {
    .menu {
        order: -1;
        perspective: 800px;
    }
    [aria-controls="menu-list"] {
        display: block;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }

    .menu ul {
        max-height: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        transform: rotateX(90deg);
        transition: all 0.5s;
    }

    [aria-expanded="true"] ~ ul {
        display: grid;
        max-height: 500px;
        transform: rotateX(0);
    }

    [aria-expanded="false"] .close {
        display: none;
    }

    [aria-expanded="true"] .close {
        display: inline-block;
    }

    [aria-expanded="true"]

    [aria-expanded="true"] .open {
        display: none;
    }
    
}

@media (max-width: 700px) {
    .top {
        grid-template-areas:
            "hero hero"
            "cta1 cta2";
        margin: 0;
    }

    .cta {
        padding: 20px 0;
    }

    /* About */
    .webDesign,
    .webHosting,
    .servisRacunara,
    .podrska,
    .statistika,
    .kontakt{
        grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    }

    .about__mockup {
        order: -1;
    }

    section.statistika {
        grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    }


}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
    .top {
        grid-template-areas:
            "hero"
            "cta1"
            "cta2"
    }

    .header-info h1 {
        font-size: 34px;
    }

    .menu {
        margin: 0;
    }

    .cta {
        padding: 20px 0;
    }

    .about__mockup {
        order: -1;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dosis" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title>iDizajner - Web Dizajn Srbija | Izrada web sajtova, izrada web prodavnica</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="top-page">
        <header class="header-line">
            <nav class="menu website">
                    <button aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="menu-list" class="website">
                        <span class="open">Ξ</span>
                        <span class="close">X</span>
                        Meni
                    </button>
                    <ul id="menu-list">
                        <li>
                            <a href="webdizajn.html">Web Dizajn</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="webhosting.html">Web Hosting</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="servis-racunara.html">Servis Računara</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="podrska.html">Podrška</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="kontakt.html">Kontakt</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            <div class="header-info">
                <h1>Web Dizajn</h1>
                <p>Budite u korak sa vremenom!</p>
            </div>
        </header>
    </div>


    <section class="webDesign about">
            <img src="assets/images/icon/webDizajn.svg" alt="" class="about__mockup">
            <div class="about about__webDesign">
                <h2>WEB DIZAJN</h2>
                <p>Neki tekst bi isto trebao da ide ovde ali moze da saceka</p>
                <p>Jos jedan tekst nekog obisa</p>
                <button id="btn-large">PROČITAJ VIŠE</button>
            </div>
        </section>
    
        <section class="webHosting">
            <div class="about__webHosting">
                <h2>WEB HOSTING</h2>
                <p>Neki tekst bi isto trebao da ide ovde ali moze da saceka</p>
                <p>Jos jedan tekst nekog obisa</p>
                <button id="btn-large">PROČITAJ VIŠE</button>
            </div>
                <img src="assets/images/icon/webHosting.svg" alt="" class="about__mockup">
        </section>
    
        <section class="servisRacunara about">
            <img src="assets/images/icon/servisRacunara.svg" alt="" class="about__mockup">
            <div class="about__servisRacunara">
                <h2>SERVIS RAČUNARA</h2>
                <p>Neki tekst bi isto trebao da ide ovde ali moze da saceka</p>
                <p>Jos jedan tekst nekog obisa</p>
                <button id="btn-large">PROČITAJ VIŠE</button>
            </div>
        </section>
    
        <section class="podrska">
            <div class="about__podrska">
                <h2>PODRŠKA</h2>
                <p>Neki tekst bi isto trebao da ide ovde ali moze da saceka</p>
                <p>Jos jedan tekst nekog obisa</p>
                <button id="btn-large">PROČITAJ VIŠE</button>
            </div>
            <img src="assets/images/icon/podrska.svg" alt="" class="about__mockup">
        </section>

    <section class="statistika">
        <div class="stats">
            <div class="counter-value" data-count="39">0</div>
            Klijenti
        </div>
        <div class="stats">
            <div class="counter-value" data-count="77">0</div>
            Projekti
        </div>
        <div class="stats">
            <div class="counter-value" data-count="3">0</div>
            Partner Agencije
        </div>
    </section>

    <section class="kontakt">
        <img src="assets/images/kontakt.png" alt="">
        <div class="naruci">
            <h3>Potreban vam je web sajt?</h3>
            <a href="#">
                <button id="btn-large">NARUČI ODMAH</button>
            </a>
        </div>
    </section>


    <footer>
        <p>iDizajner 2018</p>
    </footer>
</div>

<script>
    const navButton = document.querySelector('button[aria-expanded]');

    function toggleNav({ target }) {
        const expanded = target.getAttribute('aria-expanded') === 'true' || false;
        navButton.setAttribute('aria-expanded', !expanded);
    }

    navButton.addEventListener('click', toggleNav);

    // counter statistika
    var a = 0;
    $(window).scroll(function() {

        var oTop = $('.statistika').offset().top - window.innerHeight;
        if (a == 0 && $(window).scrollTop() > oTop) {
            $('.counter-value').each(function() {
                var $this = $(this),
                    countTo = $this.attr('data-count');
                $({
                    countNum: $this.text()
                }).animate({
                        countNum: countTo
                    },

                    {

                        duration: 6000,
                        easing: 'swing',
                        step: function() {
                            $this.text(Math.floor(this.countNum));
                        },
                        complete: function() {
                            $this.text(this.countNum);
                            //alert('finished');
                        }

                    });
            });
            a = 1;
        }

    });




</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove some margin on the different sections. It works with 10px:

```
.top, .menu, .features, .webDesign, .webHosting, .servisRacunara, .podrska {
    margin: 10px;
    font-size: 15px;
}
```

It happens because you have an image with width that expands content on mobile resolution:

```
<img src="assets/images/icon/webDizajn.svg" alt="" class="about__mockup">
```

Comment: I try it but it's still here. I check img and resize it with 50% but doesn't working again.

Comment: Yes you are right, I forget remove 350px for img size, so I put 100% and now is good. Thank you @Aitor, you save my brain today!